# How do I fit a model in Keras after getting Train and test set from Sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm pretty new to machine learning and I am trying to figure out how I would feed in data to a model after I get the train test split from Sklearn. Right now this is what I have in the data preparation phase.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(db[predictors], db["default.payment.next.month"], test_size=.2)
x_train= x_train.to_numpy()
x_test = x_test.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()
```

I set them all the numpys which I thought was necessary to plug into the model.fit() function. My model.fit() function looks like this:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, 
                   y_train, 
                   epochs=20, 
                   batch_size=512,
                   validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

and then I get an error like this:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 10000), found shape=(None, 5)
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the code of your `Sequential` model. There seems to be a problem with its `input_shape`.

Comment: You gave the wrong input_shape to your model

Comment: Here is the input_shape code
```
model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As error shows, try using `input_shape` as below:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(5,)))
```